# Microsoft Wireless Mouse 1850 disassembly

Tags: scrolling, wireless-mouse

I got a Microsoft Wireless Mouse 1850, it´s a cheap but good quality mouse. At this moment it have a problem: when i use the wheel and scroll up it  inadvertently scroll down and viceversa.
I did follow some recomendations such add lines to move and so on but without results. I suspect that the wheel is dirty , but apparently the mouse has no screws to disassemble and clean the mouse wheel , Do you know how to disarm this mouse model ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @HaroldoPayaresSalagado You couldn't find this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH0H7CsybQQ ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I love the one handed disassembly....

Comment: @Moab Ohh yeah I didn't realize that. Maybe he was holding camera with other hand which makes it even cooler. That makes him a guy who can do two jobs single handed :P

Comment: I did search at youtube, and no, i didn't find it. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH0H7CsybQQ recommended by pun you can learn how to do the job

Comment: Link-only answer is low quality; it will be useless if its target gets deleted or moved. If you cannot answer with words and pictures then the answer doesn't really fit this site. This link by itself was a good thing as a comment but we want answers to be self-contained. I like upvoting users' answers to their own questions, rewarding them for their research. In this case I won't, unless you answer the question here with words (and pictures if you want). Leave me a comment after you do this, I will upvote the answer then.